Windows Server 2019 PDC DFSR Eliminated State Inconsistencies
It has been awhile since I asked a question here.
Let us go straight to the case.
I have 2 DC.
DC A and DC B.
Both DC is Windows Server 2019.
DC A has a SYSVOL DSFR.
DC B is still in SYSVOL.
Performing dfsrmig /getmigrationstate in DC B resulted in
"All domain controllers have migrated successfully to the Global state 'Eliminated'".
The FSMOs are in DC B.
Due to the inconsistencies , DC A cannot reach to DC B with "unable to connect to the PDC emulator" when querying dfsrmig /getglobalstate
I understand Eliminated state is the final state.
Out of curiosity , I still tried dfsrmig /setglobalstate 1 but of course , returned with error "Invalid state change requested".
Within DFS Management, DC A and DC B is able to view both SYSVOL folders :
C:\Windows\SYSVOL_DFSR\domain which is sitting in DC A
C:\Windows\SYSVOL\domain which is sitting in DC B
What are my options here to make sure both DC is in SYSVOL_DFSR and synced properly?
